# Water coming out of dam gates

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I recently went to a dam and when I saw the water coming out of its gates with huge pressure. The water instantly got converted to cloudy fog and there was fog all around. Why and how this water gets converted to fog? Does pressure has to do something with this?

Comment: Instabilities on the surface of flowing water causes it form sheets and ligaments which ultimately breakup into droplets (just what happens in high Reynolds number sprays). Since the dam water is open to atmosphere, there is little change in pressure due to the flow itself.

Answer (score 1):

Sudden decrease in pressure causes some part of water to vaporise or split into small droplets
But if the dam is high on the ground it can also happen as water falling hits air and spreads as seen in waterfalls

Comment: are you saying that due to Bernoullis theorem the hydrostatic pressure of water decreases and it gets converted into little droplets or completely gets transformed into vapors?